# From html code I want the actual image to be pasted in text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code for an image I want the actual image to be pasted in text editor on paste from clipboard,Is it possible using jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(element).append('<img id="imgID" src="imgName.jpg" />')
```

**OR**

```
$(element).prepend('<img id="imgID" src="imgName.jpg" />')
```

Comment: Actually I have copied the image html code in clipboard now while pasting I want the image to be pasted not the html code is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

something like `/<img(?:.*)src=(?:"|')([^"']+)(?:"|')/i.exec('<img id="imgID" src="imgName.jpg" />')[1]` should do it.

Or if you already have jQuery `$('<img id="imgID" src="imgName.jpg" />').attr('src')` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you want to be able to paste images into a text editor on your web application, I suggest you look at a rich text editor library, like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). That would allow you to paste in images easily.